# What's the relationship between the Riemannian metric and Jacobi field?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I encounter to the question in reading the following Excise:

> Let  $(M,g)$ be a $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, and $(r,\theta^1,\theta^2,\dotsc,\theta^{m-1})$ be the (geodesic) polar coordinate. Prove that, if $M$ is a space form, i.e., with the constant (sectional) curvature $K$, then $g$ has the following expression (by Gauss's Lemma):
> $$
> \newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm d}
> \rd s^2=(\rd r)^2+(f(r))^2h_{ij}(\theta)\rd\theta^i\rd\theta^j,
> $$
> where the $m-1$-dimensional metric $(\rd\sigma)^2=h_{ij}(\theta)\rd\theta^i\rd\theta^j$ has  constant sectional curvature $1$, and
> $$
> f(r)=\begin{cases}
> \sin(\sqrt{Kr^2})/\sqrt{K},&\text{if }K>0; \\
> r,&\text{if }K=0; \\
> \sinh(\sqrt{-Kr^2})/\sqrt{-K},&\text{if }K<0.
> \end{cases}
> $$

I already know that the Jacobi-field $J$ ($J(0)=0$, $\lvert\dot J(0)\rvert=1$ and $J$ is perpendicular to the base geodesic curve $\gamma(t)$) for a manifold with constant sectional curvature $K$ is
$$
J(t)=f(t)W(t),
$$
where $f(t)$ is defined as above and $W(t)$ is a unit parallel vector filed along $\gamma$ with $W(t)\perp\dot\gamma(t)=T(t)$.

So my question is that: can we give a proof that based on the Jacobi-field? If not, what's the relation between the two problem?

In fact, I don't know how the solve the first problem, and try to use Jacobi-field to give a proof without no results.

Comment: This question is firstly post on StackExchange:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111504/whats-the-relationship-between-the-riemannian-metric-and-jacobi-field, after I read the site meta, I think is more prefer to post it here.

Comment: Actually, this is foundational material, from a first course on Riemannian manifolds. MSE is better. 

Comment: Will, I am not so sure that the question will get a good answer on MSE

Comment: I suggest consulting more than one textbook on Riemannian geometry. There are different ways to derive these formulas, and you might find one approach easier to understand than others. You can do this using moving frames and differential forms; you can also just do everything using local co-ordinates. Just fix a choice of local co-ordinates on the unit sphere and use them along with the radial co-ordinate $r$.

Comment: @Yemon, you may have a point. The OP does say at MSE that he is a postgraduate student, I think in the U.S. that means graduate student. This question is both very specific and a request for a long tutorial. If, of the first four names that come to mind, Deane or Anton Petrunin or Sergei Ivanov or Robert Bryant wanted to type out a full explanation, I would not feel that anything untoward had happened. It would be a larger effort for me, involving review from a long time ago, and I feel Deane's view is likely the best. The OP should just learn how to do the exercise as is, no Jacobi fields.

Comment: Actually, using Jacobi fields to do this exercise is not such a bad idea. It's actually one of my preferred approaches. But it seems to me that when you are learning this stuff for the first time, you shouldn't worry about doing it the "right" way or the "best" way or the "least messiest" way first. Just do it one way or another, even if it involves pages and pages of awful calculations with Christoffel symbols. Then slowly learn how to do it more elegantly. My advice is to keep struggling with it!

Comment: Thanks for all the above suggestions. At first, I just suspected that there would be a solution by using the Jacobi fields (which was comformed by Deane Yang), believing that it should be more efficient, I just stop here, do not want to have a try by the definition of section curvature. This maybe a problem  for me, especially, as a beginner. Now, I realize that, sometimes the clumsy caculation is necessary. Of course, I will have a try right now, and wish that I will work it out before exhausting my effort.

Comment: The problem with (or beauty of) differential geometry is that there are probably at least five ways to do any particular proof or calculation, and if you want to be a halfway decent differential geometer, you really should try to become comfortable in as many of the different possible approaches as possible. For example, I detest calculating in co-ordinates with Christoffel symbols and all that. But too many other people persist in using them, so you have to be able to read and understand what they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

By [Gauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(Riemannian_geometry)),
$$
\newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm d}
\rd s^2=(\rd r)^2+\tilde h_{ij}(r)(\theta)\cdot \rd\theta^i\cdot\rd\theta^j,
$$
where $\tilde h_{ij}(r)$ is a Riemannian metric on the sphere that depends on the radius $r$.

Note that $\tilde h_{ij}(r)$ is rotationally symmetric.
Therefore $h_{ij}(r)=f(r)^2\cdot h_{ij}(\theta)\cdot\rd\theta^i\cdot\rd\theta^j$ for some function $f$.
It remains to check that $f''+K\cdot f=0$.

Note that $f(r)=|J(r)|$, where $J=\tfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1}$ is a field on the geodesic $t\mapsto (t,0,\dots,0)$.
Note that $J$ is a Jacobi field --- it is a field of variation of radial geodesics.
It remains to write Jacobi equation and get $f''+K\cdot f=0$ (you know it already).